# How can we define, not one but a set of instructions for an if loop in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to give more than one instruction after a "Run Keyword If" method, but the syntax allows me to give just one? How i can give multiple instructions after condition executed as true?

Comment: Did any of these work for you @Alper ??

Comment: Yeah both of them works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an easy to read solution you could create another keyword with all your other actions inside of it. For example.

```
run keyword if    '${a}'=='${a}'    my keyword

my keyword
[Documentation]    This is documentation
Action A
Action B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyword `Run Keywords` with `AND` connector. Example given below:

```html
 Run Keyword If  '${TEST1}'=='${TEST2}'  Run Keywords  Keyword1   AND   Keyword2
```